# Enrich FileStreamResult with metadata in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, metadata, filestream

I am generating an excel file. Then I am sending it back from my controller using the following code:

```
return new FileStreamResult(
    excelMemoryStream, 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "data.xlsx"
    };
```

The `FileStreamResult` is from the `System.Web.Mvc`.

Now I have a business requirement to show a pop-up message on FE if there was no data added to the excel. There are still can be headers in the excel, so I can not just check the excel file size on FE. I need to send additional metadata along with the excel file.

I can not add another endpoint to check if there is any data going to be added to the excel. Such endpoint may result in a scenario when there is no data during the data presence check, then data gets added and then the endpoint to generate excel runs. All this results in a non empty excel being returned, but the empty excel message being shown on FE. So, there is a huge space for the race conditions.

So, my question is if it is possible to somehow enrich the `System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult` with more data in addition to the memory stream? Would be nice to be able to add an object of a custom type along with the memory stream.

The project uses `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I found. Before returning the result I am adding the metadata header as well.

```
Response.Headers.Add("metadata", "{'any': 'data i want'}");
```